# Datetime dtype is Object not Datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby, python-datetime

I'm trying to mean groupby a timestamp. First I've had to convert the time (string) that I've got into a datetime. After converting it datetime I've noticed that despite giving the specific format that pandas adds a date, I don't need a date. I'm working to remove this and keep only time object but I've not be successful. Anything that I do to remove the date returns the dtype to an Object which I can't preform a groupby on.

**Example Data:**

```
https://miratrix.co.uk/          00:01:55
https://miratrix.co.uk/          00:02:02
https://miratrix.co.uk/          00:02:45
https://miratrix.co.uk/          00:01:22
https://miratrix.co.uk/          00:02:02
https://miratrix.co.uk/app-marketing-agency/          00:02:23
https://miratrix.co.uk/get-in-touch/          00:02:26
https://miratrix.co.uk/get-in-touch/          00:00:18
https://miratrix.co.uk/get-in-touch/          00:02:37
https://miratrix.co.uk/          00:00:31
https://miratrix.co.uk/          00:02:00
https://miratrix.co.uk/app-store-optimization-...          00:02:25
https://miratrix.co.uk/          00:03:36
https://miratrix.co.uk/app-marketing-agency/          00:02:09
https://miratrix.co.uk/get-in-touch/          00:02:14
https://?page_id=16198/          00:00:15
https://videos/channel/UCAQfRNzXGD4BQICkO1KQZUA/          00:09:07
https://miratrix.co.uk/get-in-touch/          00:01:39
https://miratrix.co.uk/app-marketing-agency/          00:01:07
```

**What I've tried so far**

```
*Returned Object*
ga_organic['NEW Avg. Time on Page'] = pd.to_datetime(ga_organic['Avg. Time on Page'], format="%H:%M:%S").dt.time

*Returned Datetime but when trying to sample only time it returned an object*
ga_organic['NEW Avg. Time on Page'] = ga_organic['Avg. Time on Page'].astype('datetime64[ns]')

ga_organic['NEW Avg. Time on Page'].dt.time
```

I have a feeling there is something about datetime that I'm not aware of and that's why I'm having this problem. Any help or direction is welcome.

**####Update####**

Thanks for ALollz for providing the solution to the timestamp.

```
ga_organic['NEW Avg. Time on Page'] = pd.to_timedelta(ga_organic['Avg. Time on Page'])
```

However I'm still getting the same errror when using GroupBy using this method:

```
avg_time = ga_organic.groupby(ga_organic.index)['NEW Avg. Time on Page'].mean()
```

ERROR: "DataError: No numeric types to aggregate"

Is there a specific function for dealing with grouping datetimes?

Comment: If you don't have a `date` then the appropriate dtype is a `timedelta64` with `pd.to_timedelta`

Comment: That looks like worked! Thank you! However, still can't use groupby().mean(). Any thoughts on this?

Comment: You usually don't use `groupby` on a datetime column. You maybe want to use [resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html), so you can specify a sampling time on which to perform the `mean` operation. Note that `resample` requires a datetime index (so you want to set the `''Avg. Time on Page'` column as index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems `groupby` doesn't recognize `timedelta64` as a numeric type. There are several workarounds, either with `numeric_only=False` or working with `total_seconds`.

```
import pandas as pd

#df = pd.read_clipboard(header=None)
#df[1] = pd.to_timedelta(df[1])

df.groupby(df.index//2)[1].mean()
#DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

# To fix pass `numeric_only=False`
df.groupby(df.index//2)[1].mean(numeric_only=False)
#0   00:01:58.500000
#1   00:02:03.500000
#2   00:02:12.500000
#3          00:01:22
#4          00:01:34
#5   00:02:12.500000
#6   00:02:52.500000
#7   00:01:14.500000
#8          00:05:23
#9          00:01:07
#Name: 1, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

---

Using simple `float` values with `.total_seconds`:

```
df[1] = df[1].dt.total_seconds()

df.groupby(df.index//2)[1].mean()
#0    118.5
#1    123.5
#2    132.5
#3     82.0
#4     94.0
#5    132.5
#6    172.5
#7     74.5
#8    323.0
#9     67.0
#Name: 1, dtype: float64
```

This can be converted back with `pd.to_timedelta` specifying `unit='s'`

Comment: I get an unexpected output with this. The time changes but it doesn't actually group the indexes.

https://miratrix.co.uk/    00:01:42
https://miratrix.co.uk/    00:01:42
https://miratrix.co.uk/app-marketing-agency/    00:01:42.666666
https://miratrix.co.uk/get-in-touch/    00:02:04.333333
https://miratrix.co.uk/app-store-optimization-services/     00:01:30.666666
https://miratrix.co.uk/app-marketing-agency/    00:01:42.666666

Comment: hmm duplicates all seem to some have the same values. Got a feeling  I need to do a remove dups. Thoughts?

Comment: I was just grouping by something random for illustration. Not sure what you truly need to groupby in your real problem

Comment: the data got gathered incorrectly. I could fix it but in order to give a proper time on page estimation etc. I had to groupby and average the time. Thanks for you help. It's solved my problem :)